# Example of jqGrid TreeGrid that loads node children from JSON service on expand

Tags: jqgrid, treeview

The base problem is I have a TreeGrid that I has a significant number of nodes (over 6k) and I want to be able to load a branch when the user expands a node rather than loading all at once.

I know this is possible in jqGrid (the documentation indicates so just very poorly worded http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:adjacency_model ) but what I can't figure out is the precise set of jqGrid settings I need to make it do that.

I do have a functional TreeGrid that will load all records from the 'url' parameter, so the only trick I need is for it to only load the top node alone, and then load it's children when I click the ExpandRow.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself:

The first key is setting `loaded=false` in the child nodes I don't want loaded.  Then I need to respond the request jqGrid sends on unloaded nodes with the right nodes.